# Prove that $y_1(x)=y_2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are given the differential equation: $y''+ p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$, and also that $p(x), q(x)$ are continuous, and also we know that:

- $y_1(a)=y_2(a)$,
- $y_1(b)=y_2(b)$

and that $y_1(x)\neq 0$ in $[a,b]$.
Prove that $y_1(x)=y_2(x)$.

SOLUTION: I've been given a hint to think about the fraction $\frac{y_1(x)}{y_2(x)}$, I tried to define a new function $h(x)=\frac{y_1(x)}{y_2(x)}$, and derive it and get something that has to do with the $Wronskian$, but really got stuck there, how do I prove that the the two solutions are the same, I guess we have to use Existence Theorem, but can you guys give me any hint?

Answer (score 0):

The wronskian $w(x)= y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$ is constant ($w'=0$), so it must be $0$ because of the limit conditions. Hence $(y_1/y_2)'=0$

Comment: why is the wronskian is constant ?

Comment: One derive : $w'= y_1"y_2+y_1'y_2'-y_1'y_2'-y_1y_2"=p.w$, thus $w= C.exp P$, $P$ a primitive of $p$, but the limit condition impose $C=0$

Comment: sorry i didn't get why $y_1''y_2-y_1y_2'' = p$

Comment: This is $p. w$...